# url rewriting not working on FastCGI php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, fastcgi

My website running on Linux server with CentOS-5.1, PHP-5.4.25, Server API-CGI/FastCGI.
my rules defined in .htaccess are not working. Can any one guide me what may the issue?
Or how can I enable rewrite engine on CGI/FastCGI php?

My htaccess code is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

I tried using with and without `<IfModule mod_rewrite.so>` but no luck

Comment: Check your AllowOverride directive in httpd.conf for this virtual server

Comment: What webserver are you using? (including version)

Comment: @beerwin what is exactly syntax?
AllowOverride All

Comment: @keepwalking : how can I check webserver?

Comment: @beerwin - I added "AllowOverride All" in httpd.conf in VirtualHost file. when I tried to restart httpd server, it gave me error "AllowOverride not allowed here".

Comment: I see, that you have found the solution, but here it is anyway: `AllowOverride All` must be placed inside the `<Directory /whatever/here >` directive which is inside a `<VirtualHost IP_ADDRESS>` directive in httpd.conf.

Answer (score 0):

There was 2 times `<VirtualHost IP_ADDRESS *>` defined in httpd.conf file with my ip address, I commented one which having wrong configurations and now it worked fine.